# Does overcharging an iPhone degrade its life?

Tags: iphone

I often like to charge my iPhone for long periods at a time (like say when I'd get home I will just plug it into the charger regardless of how much battery there is left).

Will this spoil my phone by overcharging or will it in any way, degrade my phone?

Comment: Super User is not for questions about mobile devices as per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: Flag it for mod attention, and a mod will see it and move it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An iPhone (in working order) stops charging when it reaches 100%, even if you leave it plugged in.  Or are you perhaps asking about a malfunctioning iPhone, where for some reason this cut-off is not working?

Comment: so by `stops charging` do you mean to say its fine to leave it plugged in as long as we like? (i was thinking as long as its connected, even if its not charging, there is still a transfer of electricity or smt)

Comment: You're thinking of "trickle charging", which is pulling just enough energy to keep the battery topped off as well as run the phone's functions so it's not using the battery. That's perfectly okay; my iPhones have charged like that for years and are fine.

Answer (score 4):

It's fine to leave the battery plugged in after the counter reads 100%. [Apple's official iPhone Battery guide](http://www.apple.com/batteries/iphone.html) doesn't mention overcharging the lithium-ion in every iPhone.